# More efficient way to generate lattice graph with edges between visible vertices?

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

Given a *nXn* lattice, I need to generate the graph such that there is an edge between two vertices iff they are directly "visible" to each other, i.e., there is no vertex between them.

I'm using

```
latticeSize = 3;
vertices = Range[latticeSize^2];
coords = Transpose[{Ceiling[vertices/latticeSize], 
    Mod[vertices, latticeSize, 1]}];
coordsPairs = Subsets[coords, {2}];
graph = UndirectedEdge @@@ 
   Replace[Pick[coordsPairs, 
     Map[GCD[#[[2, 1]] - #[[1, 1]], #[[2, 2]] - #[[1, 2]]] == 1 &, 
      coordsPairs]], Dispatch@Thread[coords -> vertices], {2}];
Graph[graph, VertexCoordinates -> Thread[vertices -> coords]]
```

[image]

I've poked at built-in graphs to try to find a predefined graph of this sort (oh, how I'd pay extra to have a graph search engine in MMA).

Might someone know of such a built-in, or if not, a more efficient mechanism to generate them?

Comment: "efficient" as in "fast"?

Comment: @belisarius well, it's ok speed wise - I could shave time vectorizing the gcd, but really memory becomes the issue before that matters - the subsetting gets big fast. Kind of hoping someone chimes in with "...duh, that's just the built-in BigSquareGraphWithEdgesBetweenNonOccludedVertices..." (probably a version 11 addition ;-} )

Comment: Oh, Ok. Thanks. That was my guess :)

Comment: [Number of edges](https://oeis.org/A141255)

Comment: @belisarius yes, have routine that spits that attribute out instantly for numbers well beyond any graph size mma could handle...

Comment: I saw that. But OEIS [links to a paper](http://www.survo.fi/papers/LinesInGrid2.pdf) that _seems_ to contain more info. Too late here to read it

Comment: for `latticeSize = 4` some edges are missing, e.g, `2->4, 2->12, 6->16`...

Comment: @kglr - not sure what you mean - 2->4 is blocked by lattice point 3, 2->12 by 7, etc.

Comment: ciao, never mind; I used `VertexCoordinates -> coords` and messed up the vertex labels:)

Comment: Not fast, but compact, so perhaps of some interest: `With[{set = Tuples[Range[5], {2}]}, 
 RelationGraph[CoprimeQ @@ (#1 - #2) &, set, VertexCoordinates -> set]
 ]`

Comment: @Szabolcs - that's nice!